# Display app when user clicks on notification in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

I have hooked up to Google Cloud Messaging and am displaying a notification when I receive something.
I want to "maximize" my app when the user clicks on the notification. I.e. show the latest activity related to my app. Or, if the app has not started, I want to start it's main activity.

It is imperative that I do not create a new instance of the last activity if the app is already open.

How can I achieve this?

I have seen a lot of similar questions, but all the answers seem to want to specify the activity class, which I don't know, since I don't know which activity was last shown.

Is there a solution to this seemingly simple task?

My code looks something like this at the moment:

```
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
            .setContentTitle("foo")
            .setContentText(message)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, new Intent(), 0));


    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
```

But it is not working.

Comment: Use Application's registerLifecycleCallbacks to monitor which activity was last active

Comment: Can you expand on this? How does the Android OS achieve "maximization" when clicking on the square button to get an overview of running apps?

Comment: Uhh what square button

Comment: At least on Sony and Huawei, there is a square button at the bottom, to the right. You click it and are able to "maximize" apps. Thus, there must be something in the Android API...

Comment: What does that have to do with my comment about activities

Comment: That I want to maximize my app when clicking on the notification? As such, I am looking for the method related to maximization.

Comment: FYI that is called resuming an app, not maximization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your opening an `Activity` while `Notification` is clicked just open the following `Activity`. i.e. your `PendingIntent` will open following `Activity`

Please read all the `comments` written in `Activity` so that you will know why this has been created

```
public class NotificationHandlerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //deep linking - resuming app code
        if (isTaskRoot()) {
            // This Activity is the only Activity, so
            //  the app wasn't running. So start the app from the
            //  beginning (redirect to MainActivity)
        } else {
            // App was already running, so just finish, which will drop the user
            //  in to the activity that was at the top of the task stack
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            Uri data = intent.getData();
            //you can put your extra's if any
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great! Exactly what I needed :) Clever!